# find() method not working withn an async functionin mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get all the documents in command prompt or simply console.log() but the find() method is not working here is my code and what it shows on running.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


//connection creation and create a new db
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mohitChannel").then(()=> console.log("connection successful")).catch((err) => console.log(err));
 // these then and catch are the promise taker


 // and now schema
 const playListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   //  name: String, there are two ways one it is and other is given below.
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
     videos: Number,
     active: Boolean,
     author: String,
     date: {
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now
     }
 })   




const Playlist = mongoose.model("PlayList", playListSchema); // collection named playlists created.


const getDocument = async () => {
   const result = await Playlist.find()
   console.log(result);
}

 getDocument();
```

And it is showing this

C:\nodeMongo>node src/app.js
connection successful
(node:16088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Method "collection.find()" accepts at most two arguments
at Collection.find (C:\nodeMongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:238:19)
at NativeCollection. [as find] (C:\nodeMongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:191:33)
at NativeCollection.Collection.doQueue (C:\nodeMongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:135:23)
at C:\nodeMongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:82:24
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside
of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the
node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I tried the catch block but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

by the time you execute your script with `node src/app.js`, the line on where you executed `getDocument()` will run before the mongodb database connection is set,

you are using a promise to connect to mongo database, this is an asynchronous tasks that happens on the background: `mongoose.connect(...).then(...)`

`mongoose.connect` start executing, since there's nothing stopping your script to "wait for the database connection", it will continue to the next line until it reaches `getDocument()`, in this moment, the connection with the database is not set yet, that's why you are receiving an error (the error message is not helpful in this case),

to fix your issue, you can move everything inside the `mongoose.connect(...).then(<all-code-here>)`, like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connection creation and create a new db
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mohitChannel')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connection successful');
    // and now schema
    const playListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      //  name: String, there are two ways one it is and other is given below.
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      videos: Number,
      active: Boolean,
      author: String,
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    });

    const Playlist = mongoose.model('PlayList', playListSchema); // collection named playlists created.

    const getDocument = async () => {
      const result = await Playlist.find();
      console.log(result);
    };

    getDocument();
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
// these then and catch are the promise taker
```

and since you are using `async` functions, you can transform everything in `async`/`await` pattern:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mohitChannel');
  console.log('connection successful');

  const playListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    videos: Number,
    active: Boolean,
    author: String,
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  });

  const Playlist = mongoose.model('PlayList', playListSchema);

  const getDocument = async () => {
    const result = await Playlist.find();
    console.log(result);
  };

  getDocument();
}

try {
  main();
} catch (err) {
  // in case the database connection fails, do something
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this very helpful to understand and now I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is facing mongoose version 6.0 So you just have to downgrade the mongoose version. Just run npm uninstall mongoose to uninstall the current mongoose version then run npm i mongoose@5.13.8 this will install the version that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass empty object to `find()` as a first parameter:

```js
const result = await Playlist.find({})
```

Comment: I have tried it but the first answer solved my problem. And it is reasonable.  Thanks