# Mongoose find not working inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I referred this [stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971062/find-method-not-working-withn-an-async-functionin-mongoose) but still this did not help me.

I have a find method that works perfectly inside a controller but it does not work inside a async function.

Below is the cron job where i am calling this fuction inside my server.js:

```
// this performs the job everyday at 10:00 am
cron.schedule("00 10 * * *",async function () {
    await notifyBookDefaulties();
  });
```

Below i my async function:

```
const notifyBookDefaulties = async () => {
  console.log("Start");

  const getList = async () => {
    console.log("Fetching");
    const books = await Book.find({"users.dueDate": { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }});
    console.log(books);
    console.log("Fetched");
  };

  try {
    getList();
    console.log("completed");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log("End");
};
```

After execution i see the following output in my console:

```
Start
Fetching
completed
End
```

and i get the same output if i do `const books = await Book.find({});`

and if i use `await getList()` then i get the following output in my console:

```
Start
Fetching
```

and if i put a try/catch around `const books = await Book.find({"users.dueDate": { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }});` there is no error generated nor any output.

and if i remove `const books = await Book.find({"users.dueDate": { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }})` then i see the foolowing in my console

```
Start
Fetching
Fetched
completed
End
```

Below is my controller that works correctly and fetches the desired documents:

```
const dueBooks = async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Book.find({"users.dueDate": { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }});
  res.status(200).json(result[0]);
};
```

I tried to few things but it did work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put an `await` before  `getList()` call

Comment: I tried. That does not work.

Comment: Where and how are you calling `notifyBookDefaulties ` ?

Comment: Inside a cron job in my server.js. Refer the question I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be *two problems*. One is you don't instantiate your MongoDB connection when you run your cron like your controller does.

In addition to that, you should be using the `await` on your `getList` since you need to wait for that promise inside the `try` / `catch` block.

Comment: Sir I am making use of mongoose which is an ODM for mongoDB and has a different syntax for executing query. Also in my question I have mention outputs for both cases ```getList()``` and ```await getList()``` and none of them is working correctly.

Comment: Put a try/catch around `const books = await Book.find({"users.dueDate": { $lt: new Date().toISOString() }});` What does the output say?

Comment: Nothing. There is no error generated and there is no output either.

Comment: If you just drop that `const books = ...` and `console.log(books)` lines entirely, do you then see `console.log("Fetched");` print? If so, then your issue is with that line. Then try simplifying the query to `()` or `({})`?

Comment: Yes i see ```Fetched``` in my console if i remove that line. And even if i do ```const books = await Book.find({});``` There is still no output

Comment: Where are you running `await mongoose.connect` for your cron? It seems like you're just not connecting to your DB.

Comment: I have a separate function for that which gets called in my ```server.js``` when the server starts running. But that is working correctly.

Comment: Why is it separate? How will `await notifyBookDefaulties();` know about the DB connection when the cron runs it? There's your problem.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. In MVC architecture controllers are kept in separate file and we do DB connection only once when the server starts and it works perfectly fine. But for some reason this logic does not applies to simple async function. And since i was not connected to the database i was getting nothing for my query.